# How to count the crossing number of a knot with $5$ crossing?

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

We know that the linking number is always an integer. But for these two diagrams, I get linking number $-5/2$ and $5/2$. What's wrong?
[image]

Comment: Linking number is defined for _two_ curves, not one.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki What about a three components Brunnian link? So we should say linking number is defined for at least two one component link and we don't count the crossing of the same component?

Comment: I have not seen a definition of linking number for three-component Borromean Ring style links. If you want a good answer to this question, you should be clear about exactly what definition of linking number you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not computing the linking number, because the linking number is a property of a *link* with two components. Note also that when computing the linking number, you only consider crossing where the first knot crosses over or under the second knot, you don't count self-crossing.

What you're computing could be called the "self-linking number", but it's actually called the [writhe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writhe). And in fact you're computing half the writhe. In the definition of the writhe, you don't divide by $2$ when you're done summing all positive and negative crossings.

Moreover you have to be careful, because the writhe is *not* an isotopy invariant, it doesn't make sense to talk about "the writhe of a knot", only "the write of a knot diagram". To convince yourself, do a Reidemeister type I move on one of your diagrams and compute the writhe again.

Answer (score 2):

A *framing* of an oriented knot $K$ has a few possible descriptions.  I will go with the definition that a framed knot is an embedded ribbon $S^1\times [0,1]$, rather than just an embedded circle $S^1$.  This is meant to represent a basis of vectors normal to the knot, continuously varying along it.  The framing consists of a continuous family of knots, with $S^1\times\{0\}$ being $K$ itself and $S^1\times\{1\}$ being a knot $K'$, a knot "pushed off $K$ along its framing."

The *self-linking number* of a framed knot $K$ is the linking number between $K$ and $K'$.  Knot diagrams come with a standard framing, called the *blackboard framing*, obtained from imagining that we thicken the knot into a band that is everywhere parallel to the "blackboard" that the diagram is presumably drawn on.  The self-linking number of the blackboard framing from a knot diagram is called the *writhe* of the diagram.

For example, given your diagram of $5_1$, the following shows the blackboard framing and the calculation of the linking number.  Each crossing in $5_1$ contributes two negative crossings, and $-10/2=-5$, which is indeed an integer.
[image: $5_1$ example]

It's worth pointing out that every framing can be represented as the blackboard framing of some diagram.  The following diagram is a hint:
[image: Reidemeister 1 vs framing]
(This might give more intuition for why "writhe is not a knot invariant.")

So, might have gone wrong with your calculation, beyond just observing that that's not how writhe is calculated?  Given two non-intersecting knots $f_1:S^1\to \mathbb{R}^3$ and $f_2:S^1\to \mathbb{R}^3$, there is a Gauss map $f:S^1\times S^1\to S^2$ defined by $$f(s,t)=\frac{f_1(s)-f_2(t)}{\lVert f_1(s)-f_2(t)\rVert}$$
which works out because the denominator is never zero.  The linking number of the two knots is the *degree* of this map, which if you haven't heard of it roughly counts how many times the domain is wrapped around the codomain, counted with a sign determined by whether the orientation is reversed, and the degree can be calculated via an integral, supposing the knots are differentiable.  Without the push-off, $f_1=f_2$, and so $f$ has a singularity along the line $s=t$.  What you did was calculate half the degree of this map *away* from this singularity.  (More evidence of oddity is that it appears the Gauss linking integral away from this singularity converges to $0$, but Mathematica is very unhappy with the behavior of the integral so I cannot say for certain.)